# Валидация примтивного параметра контроллера в Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Есть простой контроллер автокомплита, который принимает на вход строку:

```
public ResponseEntity<NotImportantClass> handleAutomplete(@RequestParam String query) {
    // ...
}
```

Хочется провалидировать эту строку на наличие длины от трех символов, скажем, и сделать это не вручную (что-нибудь вроде `@RequestParam @Validated @Length(min=3) String query`). Есть ли у Spring такой функционал для валидации параметров in-place?

Comment: Насколько мне известно "из коробки" провалидировать RequestParam аннотациями не получится - придется заворачивать одиночный параметр в бин.

Comment: Хотя вот тут (http://techblogs4u.blogspot.ru/2012/09/method-parameter-validation-in-spring-3.html) собирают нечто похожее, на то, что вам нужно.

Comment: @Nofate видел еще танцы с `@Validated(Validator.class)` ([link](http://copyrightdev.tumblr.com/post/92560458673/tips-tricks-having-fun-with-spring-validators)), но вчера у меня не завелся ни один из способов (скорее всего, проблема где-то в конфигурации), постараюсь не забыть отписатья пр разрешении проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Как сказал @Nofate, проще всего оказалось обернуть параметр в отдельный контейнер:

```
public class AutocompleteQueryContainer {
    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 3)
    private String query;

    public AutocompleteQueryContainer() {}

    public AutocompleteQueryContainer(String query) {
        setQuery(query);
    }

    public String getQuery() {
        return query;
    }

    public void setQuery(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }
}
```

После этого можно его использовать, не забыв убрать `@RequestParam`, который больше не нужен:

```
public ResponseEntity<NotImportantClass> handleAutocomplete(AutocompleteQueryContainer query) {
    // ...
}
```

Этот подход имеет некоторый оверхед, но по мере накопления уточняющих параметров и выноса DTO и API-клиентов собственного сервиса дает свои плюсы.